# Remove Specific Contents of JSON Files

Tags: json, powershell

I'm doing analysis on servers in our environment, where the data is retrieve via PowerShell and a JSON file is created for each server. It turns out that some of the JSON is not formatted correctly and I need to loop through all the files, find the ones not formatted correctly, and remove the parts that are not correct. Here is an example of a malformed file:

```
{
"value":  [
              {
                  "Server":  "SERVERNAME",
                  "Name":  "SHARE",
                  "ScopeName":  "*",
                  "Path":  "",
                  "Description":  "",
                  "ShareState":  1,
                  "AvailabilityType":  0,
                  "ShareRights":  [

                                  ],
                  "ShareSddl":  "",
                  "ShareRoot":  [

                                ],
                  "TotalFileCount":  35,
                  "TotalDirectoryCount":  47,
                  "TotalFolderSizeBytes":  "",
                  "TotalFolderSizeInMB":  "",
                  "TotalFolderSizeInGB":  "",
                  "TreeSizeDirFailed":  null,
                  "TreeSizeFileFailed":  null,
                  "TreeErrorHistory":  null
              }
          ],
"Count":  10 (This number varies)
}
```

What I need to do is remove the following parts:

```
{
"value":  [
```

AND

```
,
"Count":  10 (This number varies)
}
```

I've tried to use `-replace` and `String.Replace()` with no luck... the parts above are still present. Below is an example of what I've done, but for testing only, it only focuses on removing the end portion. How can I go about fixing this so the replace works? Thanks!

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem -path ""

$StartMatch = @"
{
    "value":  
"@

$EndMatch = @"
,
    !!!ROW!!!
}
"@

ForEach ($File in $Files){
    Write-Host "■ Checking file: $File"
    $Contents = (Get-Content -Path "$File")
    if ($Contents.StartsWith($StartMatch)){
        Write-Host "Match" -ForegroundColor Green #test print
        Write-Host "-Checking EOF... " -NoNewline
        if (($Contents | Select-Object -Last 3) -like "*Count*"){
            Write-Host "Match" -ForegroundColor Green
            $EOFMatch = $EndMatch -replace "!!!ROW!!!", $Contents[$Contents.length - 2]
            Write-Host $EOFMatch -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $Contents = $Contents -replace $EOFMatch, ""
            $Contents #test print

            Break #testing only
        }
    }else{
        Write-Host "No match"#test print
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically you want the object inside `.value`. It's a terrible idea to do this with parsing instead of `ConvertFrom-Json` and `ConvertTo-Json` back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're interested in the objects inside `.value` property, this might be as easy as reading the file -> parsing with `ConvertFrom-Json` -> getting the value of the `.value` property -> converting that value back to Json:

```bash
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.json | ForEach-Object {
    (Get-Content $_.FullName -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json).value |
        ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
Get-Content -Path $FileName |
    ConvertFrom-Json |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty value |
    ConvertTo-Json |
    Set-Content -Path $FileName
```